# Sharing assets across different NPM Workspaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-workspaces

I have an NPM Workspaces React project and I want to create an 'assets' workspace from which all my workspaces can import images and other assets. The dir structure will look like this:

```
project/
├─ assets/
│  ├─ public/
│  │  ├─ logo.png
├─ package1/
├─ package2/
```

My question is: In the aforementioned example what would a recommended way to use logo.png in package1?

Answer (score 0):

2 possible ways:

A. Serve whats in the assets/ dir with something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). Load them in react app like CDN assets.

`<img  src="http://localhost:8888/assets/public/logo.png" alt="logo"/>`

B. Init a package.json in assets/ with same name, so it becomes a workspace package. Then you [can import from that package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces#using-workspaces) as a regular import.

`import logo from 'assets/public/logo.png';`

If direct asset import is supported (for example nextjs), then option B would work better.